# Finding objects by contained string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to select certain objects by the Strings contained in them.

For example, if i defined an array of words, say like this:

```
var searchTerms = ["apple", "banana"];
```

How can i select among a series of identical objects those that contain one of those terms and remove the containing object from the DOM?
As an example:

```
<section class="node_category">
  <h3>orange</h3>
</section>
<section class="node_category">
  <h3>apple</h3>
</section>
```

Thanks for your help!

*edited for clarity

Comment: Do you want just the `h3` removed, or its container too?

Comment: I want to remove the container :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

For example

```
    if ( $(".node_category h3:contains('orange')").size() > 0  )
    {
      //if there is any node_category which has h3 that contains orange
    }
```

**DEMO**

```js
var searchTerms = ["apple", "banana"];
searchTerms.forEach( function(value){

  $(".node_category h3:contains('" + value + "')").remove();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="node_category">
  <h3>orange</h3>
</section>
<section class="node_category">
  <h3>apple</h3>
</section>
```

If you want parent element (`section class="node_category">`) to be removed for matching `h3`, then try

```js
var searchTerms = ["apple", "banana"];
searchTerms.forEach( function(value){

  $(".node_category h3:contains('" + value + "')").parent().remove();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="node_category">
  <h3>orange</h3>
</section>
<section class="node_category">
  <h3>apple</h3>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a flexible solution you can use quicksearch too: https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch

A little exemple :

```js
 var qs=$('input#search').quicksearch('table tbody td');

 $("#append").on("click", function(e) {
     $("tr").append('<td>'+$("#search").val()+'</td>');
     qs.cache();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.quicksearch/2.2.0/jquery.quicksearch.min.js"></script>
/* Example form */
<form>
    <input type="text" id="search">
    <input type="button" id="append" value="ajax">
</form>

/* Example table */
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Test cell</td>
            <td>Another test cell</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without jQuery

```
var searchTerms = ["apple", "banana"],
    nodes = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('h3')); // get all h3's and convert from nodelist to array

// loop through h3's
nodes.forEach(function(node) {
    if (searchTerms.indexOf(node.textContent) !== -1) {
        //only remove h3
        node.parentNode.removeChild(node);

        // remove section as well
        // node.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(node.parentNode);
    }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5hb4qwmL/